# Sending credentials in secured spring-boot application using fetch API

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I was following [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/) tutorial with the only difference that I used [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for querying REST repository. My problem is that after successful authorization every `fetch()` call returns response containing login form html string. Specifically, this kind of code

```
fetch(`${root}/employees?size=${pageSize}`).then( p => p.json()})
```

produces the following error in Chrome console:

```
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in
JSON at position 0
```

If I add a header with authorization to `fetch`:

```
fetch(`${root}/employees?size=${pageSize}`, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa('greg:turnquist'))})
```

all works, but this looks silly after all effort put in configuring `Spring Security` `beans` and for sure it is not the best practice.

All java sources remain the same as in tutorial but I include fragments from configuration classes here:

`SecurityConfiguration.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private SpringDataJpaUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(Manager.PASSWORD_ENCODER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/build/**", "/main.css").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }

}
```

`SpringDataJpaUserDetailsService.java`

```
@Component
public class SpringDataJpaUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final ManagerRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public SpringDataJpaUserDetailsService(ManagerRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Manager manager = this.repository.findByName(name);
        return new User(manager.getName(), manager.getPassword(),
                AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(manager.getRoles()));
    }

}
```

`EmployeeRepository.java`

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_MANAGER')")
public interface EmployeeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Long> {

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("#employee?.manager == null or #employee?.manager?.name == authentication?.name")
    Employee save(@Param("employee") Employee employee);

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("@employeeRepository.findOne(#id)?.manager?.name == authentication?.name")
    void delete(@Param("id") Long id);

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("#employee?.manager?.name == authentication?.name")
    void delete(@Param("employee") Employee employee);

}
```

So my question is how to send credential from authorized page using new `javascript` fetch API  to interact with REST repositories without additional security configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem is that `fetch()` doesn't send cookies by default. So I should add `credentials: 'include'` to request options object:

```
fetch(`${root}/employees?size=${pageSize}`, {
  method: 'GET',
  credentials: 'include'})
```

[references](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch#sending-credentials-with-a-fetch-request)